# PHP Warning: sprintf(): Too few arguments in

Tags: php, printf

I have a cronjob which runs a script -> getting data from different itunes stores. Sometimes i get the above mentioned error message.

I think its because of special letters or something like this. Is there a way to check, where the problem exactly is? Which "special character" is respsonisble for the error. Is there a workaround for example with a IF statement?

I can´t reproduce the error, as it not appears always. Would be great to get help on this.

Here is the code:

```
foreach ($Kategorien->entry as $item) {
     $id =  addslashes($item->id);
     $title = utf8_decode(addslashes($item->title));
     $preview = addslashes($item->link[1]["href"]);
     $namespaces = $item->getNameSpaces(true);
     $im = $item->children($namespaces['im']);
     $track_title =  utf8_decode(addslashes($im->name));
     $track_artist = utf8_decode(addslashes($im->artist));
     $track_amount = addslashes($im->price->attributes()->amount);
     $track_currency = utf8_decode(addslashes($im->price->attributes()->currency));
     $release_date =  addslashes($im->releaseDate);
     $image =  addslashes($im->image[2]);
     $entry_id['im'] = $item->id->attributes('im', TRUE);
     $track_id =  addslashes($entry_id['im']['id']);
     $category_id['im'] = $item->category->attributes('im', TRUE);
     $genre_id = addslashes($category_id['im']['id']);
     $genre_cat =  utf8_decode(addslashes($item->category->attributes()->term));

     $insertSQL = sprintf("UPDATE track_itunes_countries_total SET modified = NOW(), modified_genre = '$genre_name'  WHERE id = ".$row_select_country['id']."");
     $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $con) or die(mysql_error());


    $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO track_itunes_".$cc."_total (id, title, preview, track_title, track_artist, track_amount, track_currency, release_date, image, track_id, genre_id, genre_cat, country, Online, Approved) VALUES ('$id', '$title', '$preview', '$track_title', '$track_artist', '$track_amount', '$track_currency', '$release_date', '$image', '$track_id', '$genre_id', '$genre_cat', '$cc', '1', '1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE title='$title',preview='$preview',track_title='$track_title',track_artist='$track_artist',track_amount='$track_amount',track_currency='$track_currency',release_date='$release_date',image='$image',track_id='$track_id',genre_id='$genre_id',genre_cat='$genre_cat',country='$cc'");

        $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $con);}
```

Comment: Why do you use `sprintf()` also where is `$cc` defined ?

Comment: The special character causing the problem would be `%`. Sidenote 1: Your code would work fine (concerning the special char problem), if you would not use sprintf, but direct strings. Sidenote 2: This way of constructing SQL-Queries ist easily targetted by SQL-Injection attacks.

Comment: Can you give an example how to fix it in a safe way? I'm not "so" familiar with it. PS. $cc is defined in the code -> but not mentioned in the snippet

Comment: please see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer in a tangential way, because you're using mysql_* library which is deprecated and show you PDO instead. This will either a) solve your problem or b) provide a much more informative error message that will help you debugging.

```
foreach ($Kategorien->entry as $item) {
 $id =  $item->id;
 $title = utf8_decode($item->title);
 $preview = $item->link[1]["href"];
 $namespaces = $item->getNameSpaces(true);
 $im = $item->children($namespaces['im']);
 $track_title =  utf8_decode($im->name);
 $track_artist = utf8_decode($im->artist);
 $track_amount = $im->price->attributes()->amount;
 $track_currency = utf8_decode($im->price->attributes()->currency);
 $release_date =  $im->releaseDate;
 $image =  $im->image[2];
 $entry_id['im'] = $item->id->attributes('im', TRUE);
 $track_id =  $entry_id['im']['id'];
 $category_id['im'] = $item->category->attributes('im', TRUE);
 $genre_id = $category_id['im']['id'];
 $genre_cat =  utf8_decode($item->category->attributes()->term);

 $insertSQL = "UPDATE track_itunes_countries_total 
               SET modified = NOW(), modified_genre = :genre_name
               WHERE id = :row_id");
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare($insertSQL);
 $stmt->bindValue(':genre_name', $genre_name);
 $stmt->bindValue(':row_id', $row_select_country['id']);
 $success = $stmt->execute();
 if(!$success){
     //something bad happened
 }

 //use whitelist techniques to guarantee valid, non-malicious input
 //with table names or column names. whitelistTableName is a function
 //that YOU have to write.
 $clean_table_name = whitelistTableName("track_itunes_{$cc}_total");
 $insertSQL = "INSERT INTO {$clean_table_name} 
               (id, title, preview, track_title, 
                track_artist, track_amount, track_currency, 
                release_date, image, track_id, genre_id, 
                genre_cat, country, Online, Approved) 
               VALUES 
               (:id, :title, :preview, :track_title,
                :track_artist, :track_amount, :track_currency,
                :release_date, :image, :track_id, :genre_id,
                :genre_cat, :country, :Online, :Approved)
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                title=:title_u,preview=:preview_u,track_title=:track_title_u,
                track_artist=:track_artist_u,track_amount=:track_amount_u,
                track_currency=:track_currency_u,release_date=:release_date_u,
                image=:image_u,track_id=:track_id_u,genre_id=:genre_id_u,
                genre_cat=:genre_cat_u,country=:cc_u");

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($insertSQL);
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id);
    $stmt->bindValue(':title', $title);
    $stmt->bindValue(':preview', $preview);
    $stmt->bindValue(':track_title', $track_title);
    $stmt->bindValue(':track_artist', $track_artist);
    $stmt->bindValue(':track_amount', $track_amount);
    $stmt->bindValue(':track_currency', $track_currency);
    $stmt->bindValue(':release_date', $release_date);
    $stmt->bindValue(':image', $image);
    $stmt->bindValue(':track_id', $track_id);
    $stmt->bindValue(':genre_id', $genre_id);
    $stmt->bindValue(':genre_cat', $genre_cat);
    $stmt->bindValue(':country', $cc);
    $stmt->bindValue(':Online', 1);
    $stmt->bindValue(':Approved', 1);
    //some drivers doesn't allow to have a named placeholder to appear more than once so we must duplicate those.
    $stmt->bindValue(':id_u', $id);
    $stmt->bindValue(':title_u', $title);
    $stmt->bindValue(':preview_u', $preview);
    $stmt->bindValue(':track_title_u', $track_title);
    $stmt->bindValue(':track_artist_u', $track_artist);
    $stmt->bindValue(':track_amount_u', $track_amount);
    $stmt->bindValue(':track_currency_u', $track_currency);
    $stmt->bindValue(':release_date_u', $release_date);
    $stmt->bindValue(':image_u', $image);
    $stmt->bindValue(':track_id_u', $track_id);
    $stmt->bindValue(':genre_id_u', $genre_id);
    $stmt->bindValue(':genre_cat_u', $genre_cat);
    $stmt->bindValue(':country_u', $cc);
    $stmt->bindValue(':Online_u', 1);
    $stmt->bindValue(':Approved_u', 1);
    $success = $stmt->execute();
    if(!$success){
         //something bad happened
    }
}
```

more to read here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php It's pretty easy and much better than mysql_* libraries

Expanding on the whitelisting techniques: there are several approaches to sanitize user inputs. One is escaping: this is done where the user input is "open ended" like a text input, where there is an unlimited number of possibilities. Prepared statements are perfect for this, as demonstrated above.

Another possibility is whitelisting, and it's useful when there are only limited valid possibilities for the user input (for example, radiobuttons, checkboxes, option selections, etc.) and any invalid input is either an error or malicious.

an example follows:

```
whitelistTableName($tablename){
    $allowedTables = array('tbl1', 'tbl2', 'tbl3');
    if(in_array($tablename, $allowedTables)){
        return $tablename;
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Malicious attempt detected');
    }
}
```

This is very basic but allows you to get started. A better approach would be to query your information_schema database to fetch every valid table name rather than hardcoding them by hand.

Comment: For you its easy... to be honest... i don't know, where I can or have to start here..

Comment: What does this mean "whitelistTableName is a function
 //that YOU have to write.
 $clean_table_name = whitelistTableName("track_itunes_{$cc}_total");"

Comment: @SvenJanning It may seem hard but really it is not much harder than mysql_* functions. It's just a different notation and prepared statements.
`whitelistTableName` is just a function that compares the name in input with a list of allowed table names to prevent unintentional or evil queries. That's needed because you can't use dynamic table names in prepared statements. But `whitelistTableName` isn't a native function, you have to write it yourself

Comment: Can you give me help on this. It's just that another statement reads 2 Letters from another table. PS. After reading some things, it's getting easier.

Comment: Okay, but in my case it's only one table, where the data should be stored - but it's not always the same. what's than the best way?

Comment: I´m always getting this error -> What does it mean? "PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in"

Comment: i can´t find my mistake. Can you have a look on the code?

Comment: It's not difficult, if you don't simply copy and paste what I wrote. There are more parameters on the bindValue list than parameters in the input query. You're on your own now.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how sprintf works.

[sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf) means string printf -- you are doing a printf which returns a string instead of printing directly into stdout.

printf works by assigning placeholders into a format string (the first argument), and the bound values to the placeholders as the succeeding arguments.

for example

```
$s = sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE id = %d", 'some_table', $id);
```

This is in some way a naive way to sanitize input since you are forcing variables to be cast into certain types using the formats: in this case %s and %d for *string* and *decimal/digit*, respectively. At runtime, these will be replaced by "some_table", and whatever intval($id) is.

The reason you are getting "Too few arguments" is because you are missing the bound values.

Answer (score -1):

First of all: you should use mysql_real_escape_string() or even better use mysqli instead of mysql functions since mysql is deprecated.

And for the errormessage you should have a look into the documentation of sprintf to understand the error.

Or just use proper concatination.

```
$string = "fooo='".$var."'";
```

instead of your lazy notation

```
$string = "fooo='$var'";
```

Here is an example including mysql_real_escape_string():

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='%s' AND password='%s'",
            mysql_real_escape_string($user),
            mysql_real_escape_string($password));
```

You can also give specific positions for the bound vars:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='%2$s' AND password='%1$s'",
            mysql_real_escape_string($password),
            mysql_real_escape_string($user)
);
```

And for the mysql_query(), you don't need to supply the connection link $con if you don't use more then 1 database connection.

mysql_query($query);

will do the trick.